# How to print special characters from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to read a text file and print the contents in my windows consol.
But special characters are scrambled.

*config.txt*

```
[
  {
    "beer": "øl",
    "eel": "ål",
    "egg": "æg"
  }
]
```

*code.py*

```
text = open("config.txt")
print(text.read())
```

Windows console output `python code.py`:

```
[
  {
    "beer": "Ã¸l",
    "eel": "Ã¥l",
    "egg": "Ã¦g"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open()` needs to know the enconding of the text file.
Change the code to this:

*code.py*

```
text = open("config.txt", encoding="utf-8")
print(text.read())
```

Result when running python, Windows console output `python code.py`:

```
[
  {
    "beer": "øl",
    "eel": "ål",
    "egg": "æg"
  }
]
```